# Has 10 Gbps through Linux tc qdiscs ever been solved?

Tags: linux, networking, traffic-shaping

I'm trying to use `tc` to shape traffic on a system with 10 Gbps NICs and I find that I can't get anywhere near 10 Gbps through any qdisc.  When I do:

```
tc qdisc add dev $ifc root handle 1: htb default ffff
tc class add dev $ifc parent 1:0 classid 1:1 htb rate 32Gbit
tc class add dev $ifc parent 1:1 classid 1:ffff htb rate 1Gbit ceil 16Gbit burst 1G cburst 1G
```

My throughput gets capped around 3 Gbps.  I've tried variations with CBQ and HFSC.  No matter what I do I can't seem to get around that.

Adding just the `qdisc` does *not* cause the problem (as I previously said).
I've spent days reading everything I can find that mentions `tc` and `qdisc` and "10G".  There seems to be a lot of mailing list activity 6-10 years ago (perhaps on the cusp as 10G became common, taking over from 1G) but no resolution.  Am I missing something?  Is it impossible to shape multiple gigabits/second on Linux?

Comment: What are the specs of the machine you're running this on?  Just a thought but it could be a CPU and/or memory bottleneck.  Over 1 gigabyte per second having to traverse whatever internal algorithm is involved with tc and qdisk could certainly be sensitive to general CPU and RAM performance.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up.  The machine is overspec'd or lightly loaded depending on how you look at it.  32 cores with a load average around 5, 56 GB with around 5 used.

Answer (score 4):

This is due to the qdisc locking problem (it sticks to one CPU core by default). The known solutions are XDP-redirect, XPS, and [HTB offload](https://legacy.netdevconf.info/0x14/pub/slides/44/HTB%20offload.20200722.pdf).

The XDP-redirect solution is [xdp-cpumap-tc](https://github.com/xdp-project/xdp-cpumap-tc) which creates an independent HTB qdisc for each CPU core, and then filters IP traffic into the appropriate CPU / top level HTB using XDP-redirect.

We develop an application called [LibreQoS](https://github.com/rchac/LibreQoS) which uses xdp-cpumap-tc and we've found XDP is a very good solution for our use case at least. There are some notable limitations, such as that you need to be able to divide up your traffic to about 4-6 Gbps per CPU core. That can be a lot of throughput total (20+ Gbps easily) but if you need a single HTB leaf to shape more than 4 Gbps that will not be possible until HTB's qdisc locking problem is solved in the kernel.

HTB offload is a potential solution as well. Throughput is very good. Drawbacks are that only Mellanox/Intel NICs have support for it, and its max leaf depth is 3 levels.